# Inline editing datatable - show edit button on hover (LWC)

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, html, slds, datatable

My column entries look like this:

```
<td aria-selected="true" class="slds-cell-edit" role="gridcell">
    <span class="slds-grid slds-grid_align-spread">
        <span class="slds-truncate" title={row.objectName}>{row.objectName}</span>
        <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:edit" variant="bare" class="slds-cell-edit__button slds-m-left_x-small" onclick={showEditPopover}></lightning-button-icon>
    </span>
</td>
```

And I have `slds-table_edit` as a class up on my `<table>` element. [This slds datatable example](https://archive-2_6_1.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/data-tables/) (Click 'Inline Edit' in the Variant section) shows the edit buttons showing up on hover automatically. My assumption is this is some magic that is happening with all the various slds edit type classes in the table.

My attempt at adding slds-cell-edit__button did not work, the buttons just appear there all the time and are dark instead of the light gray in the example. Is it possible to achieve this behavior with the edit button with the css classes so an onMouseOver event doesn't have to be finagled? Or is that example actually doing some mouse over event to show and hide the buttons that is hidden from view?

Comment: Hi @TylerDahle, unfortunately there is no "magic" css classes to add. You have to write your own Javascript logic to make the popup appear.

Comment: I know javascript will be needed for the popup for inline editing, but I am wondering if it is possible to get the edit button to show on cell hover without needing custom javascript through css classes or some such. The example I linked has no functionality as it all needs the javascript still, but the edit button still shows up on hover making me think that is managed by css classes. Wondering if it can be translated to lwc's

Comment: You have to click inline edit in the variant section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The edit icon visibility depends on various css classes. Here's the standard css in the lightning design system:

```
.slds-hint-parent .slds-cell-edit:hover .slds-button__icon_edit, .slds-hint-parent .slds-cell-edit:hover .slds-button__icon--edit, .slds-hint-parent .slds-cell-edit:focus .slds-button__icon_edit, .slds-hint-parent .slds-cell-edit:focus .slds-button__icon--edit {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

So if you want to use this, you have to add the `slds-hint-parent` class to the table row. Then, you'll have to add the `slds-button__icon_edit` class to the icon inside the button using the `icon-class` property of the `lightning-button-icon` component. You can use the below code:

```
<tr class="slds-hint-parent">
  <td aria-selected="true" class="slds-cell-edit" role="gridcell">
    <span class="slds-grid slds-grid_align-spread">
        <span class="slds-truncate" title={row.objectName}>{row.objectName}</span>
        <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:edit" icon-class="slds-button__icon_edit" variant="bare" class="slds-cell-edit__button slds-m-left_x-small" onclick={showEditPopover}></lightning-button-icon>
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Yes! This worked great. Thank you!